# Do we say "the city is having a blackout" or "we are having a blackout"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

This is from the dictionary

[Several neighborhoods in the San Francisco area **experienced** blackouts last night.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blackout)

So I think people will say "**the city is experiencing a blackout**".

My question is that?

Can we replace "**the city**" with "**we**" and "**experience**" with "**have**"?

Is "**we are having a blackout**" idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least in U.S. English, you can idiomatically replace “are experiencing a blackout” with “are having a blackout.”

Yes, you can replace “city” with “we” if you are in that city at the time.

No, your suggested paraphrase is not even close to correct.

First, the phrase “San Fransisco area” implies that places not in the city itself may also have been affected. So using the word “city” ignores that nuance and so is too restrictive in one sense.

Second, “some neighborhoods” strongly implies that not all of the city was affected and further implies that not even a majority of the city was affected. So using the word “city” ignores those implications and so, in another sense, is not restrictive enough.

Third, and possibly most important, “experienced … last night” means that the blackout is no longer occurring. “Is experiencing” means that the blackout is still occurring. So it contradicts the meaning of the original sentence.

Answer (score -1):

All of the following are grammatically correct:

- "The city is experiencing a blackout".
- "We are experiencing a blackout"
- "We are having a blackout"

In the united states it is colloquial to use the the following phrases:

| Sentence | When it is Used |
| --- | --- |
| Bob said to Sarah, "The power is **currently** out" | **Only** used when Sarah is **not** currently inside of a building where the electricity is turned off |
| Bob said to Sarah, "The power is out" | Only used when Sarah **is** located inside of a building where the electricity is turned off. |
| Bob said to Sarah, "The power was out at my house yesterday." | **Only** used when Sarah is **not** currently inside of a building where the electricity is turned off |

Phrases beginning with the word "**the**" are mostly used by people who are not in the same place as the listener.

`<Bob said to Sarah, "It is raining in **the** city,">` insinuates that at least one of the following statements is true:

- that Bob is **not** located in the city.
- that Sarah is **not** located in the city.

| Sentence | Are the speaker and the listener in the same place? |
| --- | --- |
| "It is raining" | Yes |
| "It is raining here." | No |
| "It is raining outside where I am." | No |
| "**The** house is experiencing a blackout" | No |
| "**The** park is full of trash" | No |
| "**The** garden looks nice" | No |

Speakers of English almost never use the word "the" to refer to things which belong to themselves.

| Sentence | Ownership |
| --- | --- |
| Tom said, "The bike is red" | The bicycle does **NOT** belong to Tom |
| Tom said, "My bike is red" | The bicycle **does** belong to Tom |

A place (such as a city) belongs to a person if that person lives in that place.

We would not usually use the word **the** to refer to our own house, or city, or other geographic location.

Comment: I am curious. Why does Bob saying  “The power was out at my house yesterday” entail that Sarah is not currently in a building without power.   I do not understand how Bob’s statements about power involve Sarah at all. Am I being dense, or do you need to edit?